# Spring binds form data to multiple (wrong) objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

I experience a weired error where the form data is bound to a completely wrong object upon submission.

I am using spring with thymeleaf and have the following form:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/backend/user/create}"
  th:object="${userInCreation}" id="userCreateForm">
  <input th:field="*{firstName}" />Create user</button>
</form>
```

The object I want to bind to is

```
public class UserInCreation implements Serializable {

  private String firstName;

  public UserInCreation() {}

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
}
```

Binding happens in the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/backend/user")
public class UserController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String createUserForm(UserInCreation userInCreation) {
    return "backend/user/create";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String createUser(@Valid UserInCreation userInCreation, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    return "backend/user/index";
  }
}
```

This works fine, despite a big issue: The data I type into the firstName field is also bound to the Spring-Security Principal, which I make available as a ModelAttribute:

```
@ModelAttribute("currentAuthor")
public User getCurrentAuthor(Principal principal, HttpSession session) {
  User author = (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
  return author;
}
```

The class `User` also has a field firstName, and this is changed. So when I type "Some name" into the form and submit, suddenly the first name of the principal will be "Some name". Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem is. Actually, I had a function of the type

```
@ModelAttribute("foo")
public Foo xyz(@ModelAttribute("bar") Bar bar) {
  ...
}
```

This is against the specification, but it seemed to work at first. But it also seems to mess up the data binding system completely.